# Why can't space agencies "splashdown" command modules on solid surfaces?

Tags: spacecraft, reentry

So, I'm watching NASA's Orion splashdown coverage and I thought of something. The Navy is taking an awfully long time to recover the Orion command module.

If braking engines (see Soyuz reeentry module) and parachutes are in use, why can't a space agency bring a command/descent module down on dry land or a floating platform designed for reentry? Wouldn't it be a lot quicker to recover?

What are the risks involved, aside from parachute failure and a crushing impact?

Even with parachutes, does a descent module just travel too fast for a solid landing zone to be safe?

Comment: Because they've done it since the 1960's, and NASA now has "safety first" as its primary guideline. I'm sorry. But at least it seems to work as it is. NASA did kill 14 of the 14 last astronauts killed in the world since the 1980's, so they do have a political pressure to try to be safer. Maybe for good reasons.